# Why is the error code on postman and on the website different?

Tags: javascript, get, header, postman, http-status-codes

I check my error code on my website by console(network tab). I see on the headers tab, the status code is `500`

[image]
[image]
But if I copy the request url to the postman and get the data, the error code is `490`

[image]

Why is the error code different?

**Note** :

If I open a new tab and call the url directly, the results are the same as in postman

My request header on the console :

[image]

My request header on the postman :

[image]

Comment: It's not necessary to put the request in Postman to get the response body. In the network tab, click the "Response" tab to see the same. Do they match between the two?

Comment: Compare the exact headers of both requests, they probably are not the same.

Comment: @Klaycon I know that. obviously it's the same. I'm asking why is it different? I want to display a message based on the status code in the headers. but the status code is different from postman

Comment: @str I have 1 request URL like the picture. in the postman the status code for the headers is 490. but why does the status code in the headers tab on the network tab be 500? It should be the same

Comment: Different requests can cause different responses. There is no way anybody can answer your question without having the source code of the API.

Comment: @SuccessMan I was asking if the *response body* was identical between the two. as in you get the same *exact* JSON error message in both the Response tab in chrome dev tools and in Postman. Anyway, like str said, it depends on the API - there may be many differences in terms of e.g. cookies and useragent

Comment: @str same request. i call the same url. only the url call is different. one was called from the website. one is called from postman

Comment: @Klaycon I update my question. I show you my body of my response on the console

Comment: A request is more than just the URL. As already mentioned, "Compare the exact headers of both requests".

Comment: seems like you might have gotten a redirect? check the headers and look at the docs for the api you're using and find `status code 503`

Comment: @Klaycon I updated my question

Comment: @str I updated my question

Comment: the second picture shows the response header, not the request header. are either `origin` or `referrer` the original URL that you requested to get this 500 error?

Comment: @Klaycon I updated my question. I request url in Postman without a request header

Comment: @Klaycon What do you think? `origin` and `referrer` are my domain of my website. I check in the script ajax javascript, I don't find return 500 error

Comment: in your question you've said `If I open a new tab and call the request url, the results are the same as in postman` - this, i assume, means the `Request URL` in your response headers is **different** from the one you originally made the request with. all the URLs are blocked out so I can't say for sure but it's either a redirect issue or a headers issue (stuff like useragent is commonly used as basic verification to prevent abuse of certain apis)

Comment: @Klaycon Yeah I open a new tab and call the url directly. why is it blocked? then how do I solve this problem? Is it must solved from backend api or from frontend website?

Comment: literally impossible to answer without knowing a single thing about the API

Comment: @Klaycon apparently the problem is in the API backend. I will ask for my backend team. Thanks